# VueJS2 property not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wrote the following code and Vue complains:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "incidents" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.

I don't see why incidents cannot be accessed?

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        responders: [],
        incidents: []
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.getIncidents();
    },

    methods: {
        getIncidents: function() {
            console.log('getIncidents');
            var app = this;
            this.$http.get('/api/v1/incidents').then(function(response) {
                // set data
                var incidentsReceived = response.data.map(function (incident) {
                    return incident;
                });
                Vue.set(app, 'incidents', incidentsReceived);
            })
        },

        getResponders: function() {
            console.log('fetchResponders');
            var app = this;
            this.$http.get('/api/v1/responders').then(function(response) {
                // set data on vm
                var respondersReceived = response.data.map(function (responder) {
                    return responder
                });
                Vue.set(app, 'responders', respondersReceived);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Possible to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er3tjyh0/) of it showing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`data` is meant for internal component data modeling, while props, which can be assigned externally, are defined using the `props` key for your component.

In other words, try:

```
var app = new Vue({
  ...,
  props: {
    incidents: {
      type: Array,
      required: false //change this as you see fit.
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

For full documentation on component properties, please refer to the [official guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).

Comment: But I haven't defined a component, have I? From VueJS1.0 I always packed up the data in my "data" container like this: `new Vue({
el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Greetings your Majesty!'
});`

Comment: Both the root vue instance and components interface properties in the same way. I assumed you have some sort of template that supplies the property values some way or another, but it seems you are getting the error while using Vue.set(...)? If that's the case, I am not sure you should be using Vue.set and I think what you're looking for is something like `this.incidents` to access `incidents` from your `data`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Didn't read the code very well for the first time. Verify that you have data inside the response and if not don't set it the incidents array.

Comment: I tried the last approach with Vue.set but I still get this error. I am assigning the variable incidents a value within the callback function, so it should work? The strange thing is, that the responders function works perfectly! It is the same structure, so I don't see why incidents is not working then

Comment: Did you try with self? Can you verify that you actually get any data inside the response just to make sure you have something there. Just noticed now that you set app to `this` :D :D

Comment: is that not working with var app = this? Yep, data is available

Comment: Is this the whole code? Don't see why it should fail